# How to prof that $L_1$ is not in $RE$ using $RICE-theorem$

Tags: computability

I was given a question to prof that a language is not in $RE$ using $RICE-theorem$

**The question:**

$S$ - property of turning machine language
$L$ - language 
$S \subseteq \{L : 7 \leq |L| \leq 10 \}$ is not an empty set.

**prof that:** The language $L_1 = \{ <M> : L(M)\in S\} \notin RE$ using $RICE-theorem$

As I know the uses of RICE-theorem is to prof that a language is not in $R$ and only if $\Phi\in S$ then we can say that $L_1 \notin RE$
From what I see here $\Phi \notin S$ so how do I use $RICE-theorem$ to prof...?

**What I tried:**

Prof that $L_1 \notin R$.

We will show that $S$ is non-trivial.

1. Let $L(M_1) = L(M_2)$, languages of the turning machins $M_1,M_2$ and both $\in S$ so from the information given we can see that if $L(M_1) \notin S$ it means that  $L(M_1) < 7 $ or $ 10< L(M_1)$ and because $L(M_1) = L(M_2)$ we know $L(M_2) < 7 $ or $ 10< L(M_2)$ that gives us $L(M_2)\notin S$.
   If $L(M_1) \in S$ it means that  $7 \leq L(M_1) \leq 10$ and because $L(M_1) = L(M_2)$ we know $7 \leq L(M_2) \leq 10$ that gives us $L(M_2)\in S$.
2. $\Phi \notin S$ ($\Phi$ = the empty languages) because the size of $| \Phi | =0 < 7$, therefor $S\ne RE.$
3. $L_0=\{0,0^2,0^3,... , 0^7 \} \in S$ because $ 7 \leq |L_0|=7 \leq 10 $, therefor $S\ne \Phi.$

So from that be can determine that $L_1 \notin R$, but given the fact that $\Phi \notin S$ I can't say anything regarding $RE$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Sorry but its largely unclear what you are talking about.

Comment: given: S⊆{L:7≤|L|≤10} , prof that: L1={<M>:L(M)∈S}∉RE using RICE.

I showed what I know so far, that is prof that it's not in R.

But I don't know how to prof that it is not in RE. @Wuestenfux

Comment: You should provide definitions and explain your notation. See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @Alan could you tell me what is it that is not clear?
I explained everything and used LaTex discrete math to ask and show my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by RICE?
Also please explain S, L, M and $\Phi$. I don't know computability-theory but that way people will be able to help you.

Comment: @LordCommander rice theorem

Comment: Is this a trivial theorem? Feel free to edit these clarifications into your post!

Comment: @LordCommander I know it as RICE : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem  but sounds the same. I need to show that S is not trivial and from that show that it's not in R and $\Phi$ ( Phi the empty language ) is in S I can understand that $S\notin RE$